# What is the a,b,c,d,e after the Amazon Availability Zone? (example: us-east-1d)

Tags: amazon-ec2

Amazon uses zones that look like this: us-east-1d.  I can find plenty of documentation about us-east-1, etc... but I do not see any reference to the a,b,c,d,e.  What does this letter represent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The letters actually show the Availability Zone: in `us-east-1d` notation, `us-east-1` is the Region's ID, and `d` is AZ's identifier.

For example, US West has (at this very moment) two Regions assigned: `us-west-1` (Northern California) and `us-west-2` (Oregon). I'd suggest checking  [**Regions and Availability Zones docpage**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) for further details.

Note that availability zones are assigned per account:

> To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones
>   for a region, we independently map Availability Zones to identifiers
>   for each account. For example, your Availability Zone us-east-1a might
>   not be the same location as us-east-1a for another account.

... so 'a', 'b', etc. are logical, not physical identifiers of Availability Zones.

Comment: There is only one section that hints to what this is.  They compare only 1a to 1a across accounts.  I think the docs really skip this topic.  This is the text I'm referring to: """To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones for a region, we independently map Availability Zones to identifiers for each account. For example, your Availability Zone us-east-1a might not be the same location as us-east-1a for another account."""

Comment: Yes, you're right: the very important point about AZ identifiers is that they're assigned per account (and do not identify a fixed entity). That makes sense, as actual Region (most definitely) has far more then 4-5 AZs in disposal, but needs to balance their load.

Comment: Are they cross compatible?